# universal makefile to include /usr/lib subdirectory

Tags: linux, makefile, portability

One of the rules in my makefile has a dependency on -lmysqlclient. On my Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit box, libmysqlclient.so files are in /usr/lib. On my other box with CentOS 6.2 64-bit, the files are in /usr/lib64/mysql. Is there a nicer/proper way to make my makefile more universal than adding the following "hack" to the makefile?

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -m), x86_64)
vpath %.so /usr/lib64/mysql
endif
```

Comment: Why not `vpath %.so /usr/lib usr/lib64/mysql` with no conditional?

Comment: @Beta: Yeah, that obviously works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a file `config-x86_64.mk` with the `vpath` line, and in your makefile do something like

```
-include config-$(shell uname -m).mk
```

The `-include` will avoid an error if the file does not exist.

In any case, each system should be properly configured so that system libraries are picked up automatically by the linker, without the need for any manual hacks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Regarding proper system configuration, I don't think I did anything out of ordinary: fresh CentOS install (minimal) and libraries were installed by simply 'yum install mysql-devel'